# When does angularjs create new scopes

Tags: angularjs

angularJS seems to create new scopes, in that there are parent scope, child scope, and sibling scope.

What determines when a new scope is created?  For example, if I use ng-inspector to view the scopes present, there is the $rootScope, and also other scopes, but it is not obvious to me what the other scopes correspond to, nor is it clear to me when these other scopes are created/destroyed.  I believe they are created/destroyed because the $id changes.  Changes occur if I navigate around and press forwards/back.

Comment: This link will explain everything https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes!

Answer (score 0):

Angular creates new scope for every instantiated controller on that part of DOM.
Angular also creates scope for every directive (except scope:false, that means for directives with isolated scope, and scope:true). A scope is also created for built in directives such as `ng-repeat` where it creates scope for every repeated item.

Also when you use `ng-if` directive it can remove and add parts of the DOM and when it adds it all the controllers and directives will add their scopes again.

Comment: Wrong, When you have nested scopes Prototype Inheritance is used!

Comment: Yes scopes are inherited in chain from original $rootScope through prototype inheritance, but that's technical detail, my answer described when that happens.

Comment: "Angular creates new scope", not true, It alway inherit from the parent. Every technical details counts, you should pass the true, not what you think Is true.

Comment: @Fals, First, it doesn't *always* inherit from the parent ("every technical detail counts")... - it doesn't, for isolates scopes. But when it does (for `scope: true`), angular, indeed, creates a new scope object, which uses the parent scope as the prototype - the object is still new

Comment: Actually it always creates new scope, new instance and sets prototype to previous parent, those things happens both. Its not only "inherited".

Comment: @tomastrajan, definitely, isolate scopes do not inherit from their parent. They may be parent-child relationship for the purposes of digest propagation (or when scopes are destroyed), but does not inherit. It can also inherit from one scope, but be "child" of another (like with transclusion)

Answer (score 0):

Angular's scope tree pretty much will mirror the dom tree.  Directives can create new scope.  Not just your directives, but also built in Angular directives like ng-if. It's a bit of an in depth topic...

Here is a [blog post](http://blog.carbonfive.com/2014/02/11/angularjs-scopes-an-introduction/) that explains things more in depth.

Hope that helps!